# Publish RTABMAP cloud_map as ordered point cloud

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, ros-melodic, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using a D435 and T256 to record 3d data with realsense_ros. D435 data is published as a ordered point cloud. Environment point cloud is assembled with RTABMAP and published as cloud_map.

Is it possible to get cloud_map published as ordered point cloud(height > 1)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/373295/publish-rtabmap-cloud_map-as-ordered-point-cloud/) by [MRRobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/39980/mrrobot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 60 on 2021-03-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't see how it could be possible as cloud_map is the point cloud of the whole map, it is not structured like an image WxH.

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2021-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MRRobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/39980/mrrobot/) on 2021-03-05**:
That makes sense. Tank you!